# Keyword repeated in tables columns and SEO keyword spamming

Tags: seo, keywords, table

I have a table that lists episodes of a TV show and I have a genre column. Google sees the words in that column as keywords and I suspect that it thinks you are keyword spamming seeing as you may have the same word repeated over and over. How can I overcome this? It seems using images would act the same as the alt text would be the same as the text it's replacing.

Comment: Can you provide an example URL?

Comment: @dan I was being vague to not look like I was promoting my site but the url of one such page is [link](http://www.animefillerlist.com/shows/naruto-shippuden). The keyword that I suspect is looking spammy to google is "filler".

Comment: Appreciated - it's a grey area here for sure, but some questions are just too broad without being able to look at the site in question.

Comment: It looks like you're just using "filler" as a category label, which Google should recognize - it doesn't look spammy to me based on the way you're using it. Is there some reason you think you're being penalized? Often people think that's the case when there are other factors (such as a delay in indexing the page...).

Comment: @dan The site is jumping all over as far as rankings are concerned and in webmaster tools under "Content Keywords" I see "airdate", "cannon", and "filler" as having the most significance.

Comment: Content Keywords is just the count of each word that the Googlebot finds - see John Mueller's explanation that [here](http://www.seroundtable.com/google-content-keywords-relevance-15882.html). If you were penalized for keyword stuffing, the result would likely be more serious than ranking fluctuations. You likely just have competition for those keywords.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not ensure that your site will be slapped. It only means that with each repetition of the same keyword, it starts getting less importance. Why do you feel your site is being slapped? There might be other reasons too. For instance, a quick run on Majestic SEO, shows me that you have no backlinks (that pass link juice).

Comment: The site is relatively new so I don't expect to be ranking high, but what i'm seeing is drastic fluctuations. I was 13th for a week then not in the top 100 for days, then back to 30 something. From things i've read that can mean google is penalizing you.

Answer (score 0):

It's time to throw away those old dusty SEO books, Google and other search engines for many years now care little about keyword density. Google has been pushing 'user experience' for a few years now and one of those factors that is less a factor is keyword density. If it makes sense to repeat a column with the genre then you should proceed to do so... because user experience is the most important factor because good sites get good links, get repeat visitors and so on....

While this doesn't answer your question if using 'Drama' a hundred times on a page weakens your page it does and it doesn't which I'll explain... It's believed that Google now uses a cap on keywords so once you're reached that cap you are no longer rewarded, of course excessive repeating of the keyword may end up in a slap but again, this would require really excessive use. Google has come a long way and I've worked a game site before and have had no problem ranking pages that repeat the keyword adventure and action for example, imdb is a great example if you look at the top 250 page, they have things like the description, so my advice would be do what your visitors will enjoy. It may be helpful to have lite descriptions of each TV show to lower the density of the genre but again, this shouldn't be your focus - user experience beats all SEO via nature links.

Comment: That is what I thought as well because it makes sense in the context of a table, but I believe my site is getting slapped as a result.